# CoffeeScript: Create a shallow copy of an object and rename/drop properties with a one-liner

Tags: coffeescript

Given:

```
externalObject = {
  UglyKeyOne: 'val1'
  UglyKeyTwo: 'val2'
  UglyUnusedKey: 'boo'
}
```

Is there a way to do the below 2 lines, in a one liner? i.e. to create `newObject`, and use the destructuring assignment in one step?

```
{ UglyKeyOne: keyOne, UglyKeyTwo: keyTwo } = externalObject
newObject = { keyOne, keyTwo }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a clean way to simply transfer those values to a new object with more preferable keys, or are `UglyKeyOne` and `UglyKeyTwo` being used in that local scope?

Comment: I'm looking for a clean way to transfer those values to `newObject`, and rename the keys in one go.

Comment: Haha, why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
newObject = { keyOne, keyTwo } = { keyOne: externalObject.UglyKeyOne, keyTwo: externalObject.UglyKeyTwo }
```

Comment: Hmph, well I guess that is the best way, just a straight assignment, no destructuring needed. Thanks. I think I was trying to get too fancy with this.